# How to find string in a file which start with 00000 and copy it in another file

Tags: python

For example I have

```
0000022c7caab3ac515777b611af73afc3d2ee50
deb46f052152cfed79e3b96f51e52b82c3d2ee8e
00000dc7cc04ea056cc8162a4cbd65aec3d2f0eb
```

I have to cut and paste the string which start with 00000 (i.e. line 1 and line 3) from a text file into another text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('in.txt', 'r') as fin, open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if line.startswith('00000'):
            fout.write(line)
```

Comment: How to remove the line starting with '00000' from input file and paste it in output file?

Comment: @Deepak:  What do you mean by cut?

Comment: How to remove the line starting with '00000' from input file and paste it in output file?

Comment: @Deepak:  There is no cutting and pasting in file processing.  If you want another file with the non-'00000' lines in it you can put an else-statement and write to a third file.  You can then replace the original file with the newly created one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `string` method `startswith`

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    print [i.strip('\n') for i in f if i.startswith('00000')]
```

Output

```
['0000022c7caab3ac515777b611af73afc3d2ee50',
 '00000dc7cc04ea056cc8162a4cbd65aec3d2f0eb']
```

Answer (score 0):

Being very slow at I/O, regular expressions, and string pattern matching, Python is absolutely the wrong tool for this task.

Use `grep`, instead:

```
$ grep '^00000' source.txt > destination.txt
```

The `^00000` pattern searches the file `source.txt` for lines which start with `00000`. The results are printed to standard output, which is redirected to the file `destination.txt`.